# Applescript send variable parameters to xslt file (updatedx2)

Tags: xslt, variables, applescript

I have an applescript that is using xmltransform to transform a xml using and external xlst file. I would like to add a variable in applescript to be picked up by the xslt file.
The satimage dictionary talks about the use of xsl params as part of xmltransform but i cannot find any examples.

Using the template `XMLTransform xmlFile with xsltFile in outputpath`
 how would i define the variables both in the applescript and in the following 
xsl file example.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0">
    <xsl:param name="vb1" value="'unknown'"/>
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="xmeml/list/name">
    <xsl:value-of select="{$vb1}"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applescript snippet

```
set vb1 to "Hello" as string
XMLTransform xmlFile with xsltFile1 in outputpathtemp xsl params vb1
```

The current applescript returns "cannot make vb1 into record".

I am now looking at using the following but it is returning NULL in the XML

```
set vb1 to {s:"'hello'"}
XMLTransform xmlFile with xsltFile1 in outputpathtemp xsl string params vb1
```

the input is

```
<xmeml>
   <list> 
     <name>IMaName</name>
     <!-- other nodes -->
   </list>
</xmeml>
```

the current output is

```
<xmeml>
   <list> 
     <name/>
     <!-- other nodes -->
   </list>
</xmeml>
```

Can anyone Help please?
many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Answer:

applescript

```
XMLTransform xmlFile with xsltFile1 in outputpathtemp xsl params {"vb1", "'hello'"}
```

XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="vb1" />

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy> 
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/xmeml/list/name">
<xsl:element name="name">
       <xsl:value-of select="$vb1"/>
    </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you are calling a XSLT with parameters, the parameters internally appear very similar to variables within the XSLT (and like parameters sent to a function), so if you pass a parameter in as a name:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0">
  <xsl:parameter name="paramname" value="'unknown'"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="xmeml/list/name">
    <xsl:value-of select="{$paramname}"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when passing the parameter in this instance you would use the name 'paramname' (although maybe something else would be better!), and the value is there in case you don't pass anything. If you do, it would be replaced.

Comment: Thanks Woody,How do I define the variable/param in the applescript. is it like.... set paramname to "Hello" </br> XMLTransform xmlFile with xsltFile in outputpath ,paramname

Comment: I suspect so, but I really don't know. Applescript was something I never managed to work out, it makes no sense!

Comment: HI woody, I updated the question. Applescript is now returning "cannot make vb1 into record" Does this ring any bells to you from a non applescript perspective? Cheers

Answer (score 1):

`xsl params` need a record or list

raw string parameter must be quoted

```
set vb1 to "'Hello'" -- added simple quote
XMLTransform xmlFile with xsltFile1 in outputpathtemp xsl params {vb1} --  {} = list
```

Comment: Thanks Jackjr300, The script is now not stopping with errors but my xsl is deleting the <name>something</name> node that I simply want to change the value of. I have the identity pass all match template. Works. The template match="xmeml/list/name" part is deleting the name node from the result though.

Comment: What do you mean by deleting? You have matched a template on the name, and when you have matched it you print the value of the parameter, so you won't have the xmeml/list/name node, you will have <xmeml><list>whatever value you put in the parameter</list></xmeml>. If you need the node as well you would need to either copy it or quote it.

Comment: Hi Woody, Im a bit mystified myself. The vb1 'Hello' value is not being parsed into the result. Im trying to find the Satimage discussion list to see how to parse this info into the xsl correctly from applescript.

Comment: Hi Woody, i contacted satimage and have posted the answer above.